# Live 555 c# wrapper

Tags: c#, c++, live555

I am completely new to c++ and have inherited a code which uses Live555 obsolete libraries. It seems there is no documentation available when it comes to developing a c# RCW for Live555 library. I am wondering if anyone has been in my situation before who can guide me to where I can start or if anyone has already developed a RCW with asynchronous Live555 can point me to any sample code. Its hard to believe if there is no code sample available for a c# wrapper or any one has not tried using Live55 libraries in a .net application. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the basics of C++ [start to learn C++/Cli](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-minutes) ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933210/c-cli-why-should-i-use-it), [even more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163681.aspx)) because with this you can write .NET libraries in C++.

You have a long way to go. Godspeed!

Comment: I would need more than Godspeed!!! is there any existing C++/CLI wrapper available for asynchronous Live555?

Comment: At a first glance: No. But since Live555 is coded in C++ maybe you could compile it using the `/clr` flag (i.e. as C++/Cli). Then you only have to worry about marshalling (moving data from managed to unmanaged memory and vice versa). The effort of this may be small or huge depending on the interface of Live555 (which I, in fact, don't know).

Comment: Please don't forget to vote up this answer if it helped you and accept it in case it was the answer you were looking for.

Comment: I compiled the code using /clr and /TP switches and it has generated object files. I thought it would generate a dll which I can 'refer' in my C# code. I have not done interop before so please ignore my limitations but I am not able to get the concept of /clr option. can you explain what does the option /clr does exactly.

Comment: That goes a bit beyond the original question but it's quite easy to find information on that one, e.g. [compiler flag /clr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s.aspx) and [the Common Language Runtime in general](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bs2ecf4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks for taking time in replying. what i was originally looking for a few code samples in c#/vb.net for wrappers and I dont think i got what i wanted. trying the compile switch which you adviced has taken me no where. considering that you took time and made effort to help me, and I appreciate that, i am marking it as an answer but who so ever might be in my situation looking for the answers will not find it very useful.

Comment: While I'm happy getting rep points, I'd rather get them for THE RIGHT answer ;-). So, if this is *not* the right answer in any way, un-check it.